# Converting from Cartesian polar coordinates

Tags: calculus

I am wondering whether I converted the following correctly.

In Cartesian coordinates:

$$\int_{-2}^{0}\int_{0}^{(4-x^2)^{1/2}}x^2(y) dydx$$

In polar coordinates would this be

$$\int_{\pi/2}^{2\pi}\int_0^{2}r\cos(\theta)^2r\sin(\theta)(r) drd\theta$$

$\int \int (x^2+y^2)$, with $d$ domain a disk of radius $3$ centered at origin.

Would this be the following integral?

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{3}r^2(r)dr\theta$$

Comment: I don't understand why the integral $\iint\limits_D \left(x^2 + y^2\right) \, dA$ you mention at the start of the third sentence appears there.  Is this a typo?

Comment: Are these two separate questions?  Two separate integrals you want to convert to polar?

Comment: yes sorry yes there are two seperate integrals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first think about the limits of integration.  The area you are integrating over is the set
$$
D = \left\{ (x, y) \, \big| \, -2 \leq x \leq 0, \, 0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{4 - x^2} \right\}.
$$
This is the portion of the circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin which lies inside of the second quadrant (the $x$-values are negative, but the $y$-values are positive).

In polar coordinates this becomes the collection of $(r, \theta)$-pairs where $0 \leq r \leq 2$ (because we have a circle of radius 2 centered at the origin), but where $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \pi$ (because of the second quadrant).

This immediately tells you that the integral will appear in polar coordinates as
$$
\int_0^2 \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \cdots r \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta
$$

Now we need to convert the integrand.  Just use the formulae $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$ and the $x^2y$ you're integrating becomes $r^2 \cos^2\theta \sin\theta$.

Putting it all together, the integral is
$$
\int_0^2 \int_{\pi/2}^\pi r^3 \cos^2\theta \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta
$$

Your second integral is essentially correct, but your notation is off.  I would write the integral as
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^3 r^3 \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta.
$$